# Count function()

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two table with some data sample in them. I would like to to pull out number of classifieds in each category. I gave it a try, and I got (2) in each one which is not correct. So hopefully someone will help me with this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subcategory_id` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `subcategory_id`, `parent_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Announcements', 0, 0),
(2, 'Employment', 0, 0),
(3, 'Items For Sale', 0, 0),
(4, 'Services', 0, 0),
(5, 'Garage Sales', 0, 0),
(6, 'Automobiles', 0, 0),
(7, 'Announcement1', 1, 1),
(8, 'Announcement2', 1, 1),

--
-- Table structure for table `classifieds`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `classifieds` (
  `classified_id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `authorized` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`adid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=177 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `classifieds`
--

INSERT INTO `classifieds` (`classified_id`, `title`, `description`, `category_id`, `name`, `authorized`) VALUES
(1, 'Test Classified', 'Here is the First Test classified listing.', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO `classifieds` (`classified_id`, `title`, `description`, `category_id`, `name`, `authorized`) VALUES
(2, 'GMC For Sell', 'Looks like new 1979 GMC.', 6, 1);
```

here

```
$query = "SELECT category_id, COUNT(title) FROM classifieds GROUP BY category_id"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$num_items_in_category = $row['COUNT(title)'];
echo "<><a href='category-".$row['id'].".php' >".$row['name'].$num_items_in_category."</a></li>";
```

Thanks

Comment: First, you should give an alias to the `COUNT(title)`. Second: where do `$row['id']` and `$row['name']` come from?

Comment: I've tried it this way: $query = "SELECT category_id, COUNT(title)as 'total' FROM classifieds GROUP BY category_id"; but no luck

Comment: As a side note: Your `INSERT INTO classifieds` statements don't have a matching number of parameters, looks like `name` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SQL a bit, and loop through the results?

```
$query = "SELECT c.id, c.name,
                 COUNT(cl.category_id) AS num_items_in_category
              FROM category_id c
                 LEFT JOIN aclassifieds cl ON cl.category_id=c.id
              GROUP BY c.id";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li><a href='category-".$row['id'].".php' >".$row['name'].$row['num_items_in_category']."</."</a></li>"; 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't have a table called category_id or aclassifieds.

Comment: And what if you change `category_id` to `categories` and `aclassifieds` to `classifieds`?

Comment: Changed it a bit and it works perfect :) Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else wants to benefit my this:

```
enter $query = "SELECT c.id, c.name,
             COUNT(cl.title) AS num_items_in_category
          FROM categories c
             LEFT JOIN classifieds cl ON cl.category_id=c.id
          GROUP BY c.id";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "

".$row['name'].$row['num_items_in_category']."

"; 
}
 here
Thanks